# Check if the node exist in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml:

```
<Rejectedparameters>
  <parameter>
    <name>CO</name>
    <value>5.34</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>CO2</name>
    <value>10.1</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>HC</name>
    <value>473</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>O2</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </parameter>
</Rejectedparameters>
```

I need to check if for example a node exists - like this :

```
  int Gvalue = (from x in document.Elements("Rejectedparameters").Elements("parameter")
                from p in x.Elements("Name")
                where x.Element("CO").Value.ToString() != string.Empty
                select x).Count();
```

but the Gvalue is 0 - why? As you can see, the `CO` is exists in the XML.

Comment: `Name` and `name` aren't the same - XML is case-sensitive. Additionally, you're trying to find an *element* called `CO`, and there's no such element in your document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, each `parameter` element only has a single name, so just use `Element` for that.

Next, use `name` as the element you're looking for, not `Name`.

Finally, you're looking for a *value* of `CO`, not an *element* called `CO`. So you'd have something like:

```
var query = doc
    .Root
    .Elements("parameter")
    .Where(parameter => (string) parameter.Element("name") == "CO" &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) parameter.Element("value"));
var count = query.Count(); // It's not clear why this was Gvalue in your original code
```

I've guessed at what you were trying to do with the check for an empty string... you may not need the second part of the filter. I've assumed that you don't *only* want to get the count - that you actually want to use the elements too.

An alternative approach would be to convert all the parameters with a query first:

```
var parameters = doc.Root.Elements("parameter").Select(p =>
    new { Name = (string) p.Element("name"), Value = (string) p.Element("value") });
// Just as an example...
var co = parameters.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "CO");
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `CO` is not element. It is value. And you should change your query;

```
var gValue = document.Descendants("name").Count(x => x.Value == "CO");
Output : 1
```